# How to set a maximum width with flexbox and avoid jumps with media queries

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have 3 boxes with 3 products (Ragnar, Thor and Odin) created with flexbox. They work perfectly on a mobile version but when I resize the browser window to tablet and desktop versions, the boxes become suddenly bigger due to the media query. I'm working with `max-width` in pixels. I want to make it more responsive and I'm not sure how.

**To sum up, the boxes should rescale and change their width smoothly until they reach to their maximum width and be narrower than the rest of the main elements.**

Here's the link of the pen: https://codepen.io/aitormorgado/pen/MWayXPy

Here's the code for the section ID and the box class:

```
#models-section {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 5.5rem;
}

.product {
  margin: 3rem auto;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
  line-height: 1.8;
  max-width: 260px;
}
```

And this is the media query:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  html,
  body {
    max-width: 70vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .product {
    max-width: 400px;
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried it out and found out your code needs only very few minor changes. Set your `.product` to the following widths:

```
.product {
    margin     : 3rem auto;
    border     : 1.5px solid black;
    line-height: 1.8;
    min-width  : 260px;
    width      : 40%;
}
```

And remove the width in your media query. It may not be perfect. But from this point you should be able to optimise it on your own.

You've set your widths very fixed to 260px and 400px for wider screens. You let no room for transitions between the two values. A relative value with % should fix it.

However, your code has some other dependencies, which I'm not able to control. Good luck!